# Draw a line with Scaffold widget

Tags: flutter

My goal is to draw a line, however, it is not working.
I find out that the size parameter in paint function is always 0
why ? what should I change in order to make it works

```
class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  var paint = Paint();
  paint.color = Colors.green[800];
  paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
  paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
  var path = Path();
  path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
}
@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return true;
}
}
class Home extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Test'),
    ),
    body: Center(child: CustomPaint(painter: CurvePainter)),
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code beow 
Step 1 : You can wrap with `Container` to provide size 
Step 2 : You need `path.close()` and `canvas.drawPath()` 
Step 3 : `CurvePainter` typo need `CurvePainter()`, you loss `()`

code snippet

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.green[800];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
    var path = Path();

    print(size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
...
body: Center(
          child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: CustomPaint(painter: CurvePainter())))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.green[800];
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 2.0;
    var path = Path();

    print(size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: CustomPaint(painter: CurvePainter()))),
    );
  }
}
```